# best way to start with google flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I tried flutter docs but it seems completely new pattern in everything. 
What is best way to start with flutter.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to start by the official get started guide [here to install and try first app](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install) then start to explore [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/learn-more)

Then you have a list of ressources to explore according to what you want to do [here](https://github.com/Solido/awesome-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

There are youtube channels listed on [Awesome Flutter](https://github.com/Solido/awesome-flutter#videos) repo.

You can also try codelabs from google, which helps you understand basics.

[write your first flutter app](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/first-flutter-app-pt1/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0)

Search 'flutter' in [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/) for more codelabs

[Udacity course](https://www.udacity.com/course/build-native-mobile-apps-with-flutter--ud905) and there are probably many udemy courses.

I would suggest udemy courses if you are new to programming and mobile app development. If you are experienced with programming, codelabs and documentations are enough.